# add a co host to google meet before the main host logging in and limiting the duration of it with google calendar api in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-calendar-api, google-meet

is there a way to set a host to a meeting conference before the main host start the meet?
and is there a way to have a setting that would limit the duration of each Google Meet class created to 1.5 hours ?
im using google calendar api in java

in java i can create a google meet conference via google calendar api and now i want to add a co_host before the main host starting it and limit the duration of my meet classes to 1.5 hour